# cocos2d looks like it is well supported and widely used, are there other good choices?

Tags: ios, open-source

I've been googling a bit and looking for ios game frameworks. It looks like cocos2d has the mindshare, and it looks like it has an active community. It also fits my budget ($0.00), as this is really more for fun than anything else.

Are there other open source alternatives worth looking at?

To be a bit more specific on criteria, I'm interested in the following.

- ios
- open source
- well used (i.e. used on more than a few games)
- active community
- should provide benefits over just doing it 'on your own'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best game engine 2D for iOS](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10059/best-game-engine-2d-for-ios)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't find that while searching. That question did not provide much in the way of higher level criteria, and as a result ended up with a very long list of possibilities. I've edited my question and tried to provide better criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Cocos2D should fit your criteria very well. So it may well be a good idea to look into it a bit further, and only look for something else if you really dislike Cocos2D for any reason.